# Can I use an HTML base tag to resolve a virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, virtual, relative-path, virtual-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application running in IIS as a subweb; let's say its path is something like http://mysite.com/subweb.

I have a view which serves content obtained from a CMS.  The CMS editor has entered some content containing a relative image path <img src="/images/imga.png" />.

This works fine on the production server where the site is the root website, but not on the staging server where the site is a virtual directory under the root website

The path should be <img src="/images/imga.png" /> on the production server

and <img src="/subweb/images/imga.png" />  on the staging server.

Is it possible to use the <base> tag to resolve this image path?

```
<head>
<base href="http://mysite.com/subweb/" />
</head>

<html>
  <body>
    <img src="/images/imga.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone explain why or if this is a workable approach?  I don't want to require the content editor to have knowledge of the website deployment option (which changes between UAT and production).

Comment: The <base> tag specifies a default address for hyperlink in the page. I guess it does nothing on the image src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
   <img src="images/imga.png" />
```

to make it a relative URL. Of course it's not that easy, the content editor must be changed. But I do believed that is the problem. URLs starting with a `/` are resolved from... (*wonders*) the domain's top-level directory?

Answer (score 1):

The base tag only affects relative URLs.  Try changing your image tag to this:

```
<img runat="server" src="~/images/imga.png" />
```

This will work even in sub directories of your app.  .Net will resolve the "~/" to your application root.

Comment: This is not a workable resolution because I can't depend on the content editor to always add the runat="server" attribute or the ~ character.

Comment: @Keith To avoid the runat="server" attribute, you can use <%Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/images/imga.png")%> instead.